# What does the crystal represent in the new Naruto Op (ep 432)

Tags: naruto

[image]

I can think of a few meanings for the crystal, but I was wondering if there is anything "official" stated or if it was related to an actual crystal in the series?

Or maybe its just that someone on the Naruto production team likes Final Fantasy.

Comment: Isn't that the crystal that tsunade gave him to help control the kyubii? Or am I mistaken there?

Comment: @Thomas the necklace she gave him was more of a long rectangle gem looking thing rather than a crystal

Comment: I like to think they are souls or dreams

Answer (score 2):

After watching the opening, here's my version :

> It's all about the collective hopes and dreams people have for one
>   another and themselves. All of the dead characters passed down the
>   circular stone that represented the hopes they had for Naruto, who
>   embodied the future. Naruto struggled to achieve the goal by
>   struggling no matter how tired he was. Or this crystal can also be the past, that's why Sasuke would want to destroy it (but later, he accepts it).

Comment: is this an official statement from the author?

Comment: No. As I have stated, it's my own analysis or understanding on the opening.

Comment: Then this does not answer my question. My question asks for official sources for the symbolism behind the crystal.

Answer (score 0):

The crystals represent bonds. They're not tied to one person. They're all bonds passed down from different people to different people. Naruto has been looking for BONDS all his life. Sasuke wanted it as a child, but after his brother's betrayal he seeked to sever those BONDS, Madara used to want what's best for the world, reaching for it and still believing what he did was for the greater good, only to realize he's been used by Kaguya from the moment his little brother died, hence her grabbing his bonds and severing it.

Comment: is this an official statement from the author?

Answer (score -1):

I think the stone symbolizes hope and peace for the shinobi world.  Naruto embodies the crystal, which is why he saves everyone from tragedy and darkness.  He has the power to change people for the better, and that is why it is passed down from generation to generation so everyone can have the hope to create peace in their hearts.